# CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'master' on Amazon AWS RDS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I followed the instructions on AWS to set up an RDS instance with SQL server Express,

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_NET.quickstart.html

But I find that when I go to run the commane 'Update-Database' that I get:

CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'master'.

Turns out I'm logged in as 'Guest'??? Despite setting up the db as per instructions.

So I'm expecting that I must have missed something simple, just looking for any hints as to how to get admin access to my own SQL Server hosted on RDS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `master` database is a System database internal to SQL Server. You never need to run `CREATE TABLE` inside that database. It sounds like you're not in the right database context: you're running commands against that database rather than your own database.

Comment: Ok I get what you're saying but how can I create a database if I dont have access? there are 4 'database' available:

master,
msdb,
rdsadmin,
tempdb...

Should I just remove this 'Initial Catalog=master;' from the connection string?

Should I just use msdb?

Comment: OK I changed the Initial-Catalog in the connection string to a new name and that fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: @DaveTheKiwi did you use an existing database name, one that you created manually for Initial-Catalog? I have the same issue myself...